# I am getting an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

```
const ProductScreen = ({ history }) => {
  ...

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    history.push(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`)
  };
```

This the code, I know there is a problem in this part of code but don't know to solve it.

I am using `react-router-dom@6.8.2`. I tried using `this.context` and `this.prop` but they are also throwing a error. Is there a problem with using prop in such a way?

This my github [link](https://github.com/niruparekh09/shopee-website/blob/main/frontend/src/screens/ProductScreen.js) of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router-dom@6` removed the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) that existed previously in RRDv5, there is no passed `history` (*or `match` or `location`*) prop. Import and use the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook to access a `navigate` function that can be called in callback functions.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductScreen = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    navigate(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`)
  };

  ...

};
```

`react-router@6` introduced a ton of breaking changes, I *highly* recommend looking over the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) to see what changed.